# DBD::Oracle: load_file:The specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, oracle, perl, dll

It's a story as old as time itself.  No, I'm not talking about the story of a man's wife running off with his best friend.   I'm talking about getting `DBD::Oracle` to work.  Although both stories have about the same amount of pain associated with them.

Let us start with the facts:

- Running Windows 7 -64 bit
- Running Strawberry Perl (v. 5.16.3 - 32 bit)  (the reason we have 32 bit is because there is a module that is only 32 bit and we are stuck with it - don't ask)
- Oracle Client (version 12.1.0 - 32 bit) successfully installed.
- The bin directory of said Oracle Client has been included at the front of the `PATH`
- the addition of the following environmental variables:

  ORACLE_HOME - pointing to Oracle Client path
  TNS_ADMIN -pointing to Oracle Client path
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH - pointing to Oracle Client path
  ORACLE_USER_ID - set to a valid oracle user in the form: user/pass@system:port\sid
  ORACLE_SID - set to valid oracle sid
- Successful connection of sqlplus to the desired database.
- "Successful creation" of DBD::Oracle into Strawberry Perl using `cpanm`.   Although I had to use `--force` because the tests failed.
- An entry entered into tnsnames.ora, that I assume is correct:

  *nameIMadeUp*.WORLD =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *servername*)(PORT = *port#*))
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SID = *sid*)
      )
    )

After all of that, we try to run this code (snipped for the sake of brevity):

```
use DBI;
use DBD::ODBC;
use Log4Perl;

#logger set up here.

my $user = "username";
my $passwd = "password";
my $DSN = "dbi:Oracle:host=servername;sid=sid;port=port#";

my $oracleDbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$user,$passwd) or $logger->logdie("$DBI::errstr\n at line:".__LINE__);
```

And we get this glorious error:

```
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load 'C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.dll' for module DBD::Oracle: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 190.  
at (eval 84)[C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/DBI.pm:770] line 3. 
Compilation failed in require at (eval 84)[C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/DBI.pm:770] line 3. 
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
...stacktrace...
```

So, I have read that 'C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.dll'  is looking for oci.dll which is causing the error.   However oci.dll is in [oracle_client_path]/bin/.   Theoretically, it should be able to find it.

Or is it looking for another dll?   are there tools in windows or maybe even visual studio that can help here?

Or is there some magical step that I am missing?

I thank you in advance for any wise sage knowledge you put forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, a reboot was needed.  After the reboot, connections through Perl were possible.  This is here in case someone is as stupid as me.   I'm going back my AS/400 now...